# How do I get a component to render after each loop iteration rather than waiting until the loop has finished?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a calendar type page in my app which has to calculate the appointments due on that day. This operation only takes about 35ms per day but when you're looking at a month, it adds up. Currently, as I am looping through my dates, nothing is rendered until ALL the days have been loaded.

I thought I'd try and get a simpler example to test with so:

```
<span v-for="n in 100000000">{{ n }} </span>
```

Even doing something as simple as this, the span won't render until it's been through all 100 million iterations.

How can I get this to render 1 then 2, then 3 etc rather than rendering when it's completed the loop?

Edit: This is my real world example:

```
<planner-day
          v-for="date in getDates(index, index + selectedFilters.daysPerRow)"
          v-if="plannerStartDate"
          :date="date"
          :timeDisplayType="selectedFilters.timeDisplayType"
          :timeInterval="selectedFilters.timeInterval"
          :jobs="items"
          :filteredDateRange="selectedFilters.dateRange"
          :jobDueDates="jobDueDates"
          :roundJobCounts="roundJobCounts"
        ></planner-day>
```

`index` above is from an outer loop. This is `getDates()`:

```
getDates (rowIndex) {
    let rangeStart = parseInt(rowIndex) * parseInt(this.selectedFilters.daysPerRow)
    let rangeEnd = rangeStart + parseInt(this.selectedFilters.daysPerRow)
    let dates = []
    let currentRow = 0
    var currentDate = this.selectedFilters.dateRange.start.clone().subtract(1, 'days')
    while (currentDate.add(1, 'days').diff(this.selectedFilters.dateRange.end) <= 0 && currentRow < rangeEnd) {
      if (currentRow >= rangeStart) {
        dates.push(currentDate.clone().startOf('day'))
      }
      currentRow++
    }
    return dates
  }
```

Comment: Is this the behaviour you are desiring for? See fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/r_vamsi_krishna/brs4Lpgc/1/)

Comment: @VamsiKrishna Yes it is. In my real life example, I'm looping through some dates and showing a component instead. How would that work in this instance? I'll add my code to the OP.

Comment: can you even show the dates [ ]

Comment: @VamsiKrishna Sorry, I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: I've just tried: `<span v-for="date in getDates(index, index + selectedFilters.daysPerRow)">{{date}}</span>` and it shows them all at once. I'm assuming I should be feeding the array using push in the same way your jsFiddle does?

Comment: What i did in my fiddle was I added an `arr[ ]` reactive property in the data option and then to this array pushed items. In your case the `getDates()` is using index as an argument which is coming from an outer loop. Implementing this is tricky. I'll try it out and let you know

Comment: after some testing added an answer.. please let me know if its working for you...:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this using a directive like this:

```
<outer-loop v-for="(item, index) in myArray"  v-getDates="index">

    <planner-day v-for="date in myDates"></<planner-day>

</outer-loop>
```

In the component script

```
        data(){
    return{
        myDates:[]
    };
},
directive:{
    getDates: {
        bind(el, binding, Vnode){
            var vm = Vnode.context;
            var index = binding.value;
            let rangeStart = parseInt(index) * parseInt(vm.selectedFilters.daysPerRow)
            let rangeEnd = rangeStart + parseInt(vm.selectedFilters.daysPerRow)
            let currentRow = 0
            var currentDate = vm.selectedFilters.dateRange.start.clone().subtract(1, 'days')

            var myLoop = function(i){
                if (i >= rangeStart) {
                    vm.myDates.push(currentDate.clone().startOf('day'));
                  }
                if(currentDate.add(1, 'days').diff(vm.selectedFilters.dateRange.end) <= 0 &&  i < rangeEnd){
                    i++;
                    myLoop(i);
                }
            }

            myLoop(currentRow);

        }
    }
}
```

The loop will be adding items to `myDates[ ]` array. Since `myDates[ ]` is initialized in data option it is reactive and you can loop through it.

Here is the [example fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/r_vamsi_krishna/2d0fu8nz/1/)

Comment: This looks very promising, as soon as I get a moment, I will test it. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, this didn't work out of the box BUT it did work when I put a `setTimout(function () { /* loop code */ }, 1)` in place. Without the timeout, it was waiting for all components to be fully loaded but with the timeout, I can see each component rendering as it's added. Thanks for your help on this and I appreciate you going the extra mile with the example and directive. I wouldn't have thought to do that.

Comment: @webnoob happy to help:)